# Tilestrata XML error

Tags: tiles, mapnik

I am trying to install [Tilestrata](https://github.com/naturalatlas/tilestrata) on a DigitalOcean server. I already have it up and running on an AWS instance. But although I think I'm doing the same thing I did to install it on AWS, so far I have been stymied in getting it running on DO by the following error:

```
safeuser@Server:~/tileserver$ node server.js

/home/safeuser/node_modules/tilestrata/lib/TileServer.js:499
    var callback = function(err) { if (err) throw err; };
                                                  ^
Error: Unable to initialize "basemap" layer: "expected < at line 1"
    at /home/safeuser/node_modules/tilestrata/lib/TileServer.js:106:19
    at /home/safeuser/node_modules/tilestrata/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at done (/home/safeuser/node_modules/tilestrata/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:243:17)
    at /home/safeuser/node_modules/tilestrata/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
    at Object._onImmediate (/home/safeuser/node_modules/tilestrata/lib/TileRequestHandler.js:125:4)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:330:15)
```

It seems like it's having issues with the Mapnik XML file, but I've checked the file and the route to the file, and it should be fine. It's the exact same project.xml file I'm using successfully on AWS. Here is the contents of my server.js file:

```
var tilestrata = require('tilestrata');
var disk = require('tilestrata-disk');
var mapnik = require('tilestrata-mapnik');
var dependency = require('tilestrata-dependency');
var strata = tilestrata();

// define layers
strata.layer('basemap')
    .route('tile.png')
        .use(disk.cache({dir: './tiles/basemap/'}))
        .use(mapnik({
            xml: './project/project.xml',
            tileSize: 256,
            scale: 1
        }));

// start accepting requests
strata.listen(8080);
```

I must be missing something here, and I've been investigating for days. Any insights would be most welcome.

Answer (score 3):

What you're encountering is an unfortunate side-effect of a breaking change in [0.4](https://github.com/naturalatlas/tilestrata-mapnik/releases/tag/v0.4.0) of [tilestrata-mapnik](https://github.com/naturalatlas/tilestrata-mapnik) ([changelog](https://github.com/naturalatlas/tilestrata-mapnik/releases/tag/v0.4.0)). When specifying the path to an XML file, use `pathname` instead of `xml`. This parameter change was in order to accommodate people specifying XML that's in memory, not on disk.

Sorry about that!